# Rearrange row elements using numpy in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm very new to python so i would appreciate any help I can get.  How can I rearrange A to look like B?

```
A=([3,5,6,9,0,0,0,0,0])
B=([0,0,3,0,5,6,0,0,9])
```

Specifically, I want to rearrange A using the the entries as an index.  So I want the 3rd, 5th, 6th, and 9th elements of B to be the value of that index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this is tagged numpy, here's a numpy solution:

```
In [11]: A = np.array([3,5,6,9,0,0,0,0,0])
```

Extract the poisition of the nonzero elements in A:

```
In [12]: np.nonzero(A)[0]
Out[12]: array([0, 1, 2, 3])

In [13]: ind = A[np.nonzero(A)[0]]
```

Trimming the zeroes may be equivalent (depending on the rules of the game):

```
In [14]: np.trim_zeros(A)
Out[14]: array([3, 5, 6, 9])
```

Create a B of zeroes and then fill with ind:

```
In [15]: B = np.zeros(A.max() + 1)

In [16]: B[ind] = ind

In [17]: B
Out[17]: array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  3.,  0.,  5.,  6.,  0.,  0.,  9.])
```

Comment: depending on rules (and the solution you want), A.max() may be len(A) instead.

Comment: To match the OP's desired result, I think you need `B = B[1:]`.

Comment: Good catch, could also fix using `B = np.zeros(A.max())` and `B[ind - 1] = ind`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution! Appreciate a solution without a loop.  I did want the solution with len(A) instead of A.max(). If i skip a few steps and do `B[A-1]=A]` I get the same answer, but if I use len(A) instead of A.max(), then the last element in B becomes 0 instead of 9.  Can you explain why this happens?

Comment: in python (numpy/C etc.) indexing starts at 0 (so we get off by one errors trying to get what you want, indexing starting at 1). np.zeros creates an array of the length you pass it, so try with `len(A) - 1`...?

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you don't have any duplicate element in A or the element that is larger than the length of the list A. Then, using list comprehension,

```
B = [ i if i in A else 0 for i in range(1,10) ]
```

would work.

---

#### Explanation:

First, a list comprehension

```
[i for i in range(1,10)]
```

gives `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`. You want to put `0` if an element in this list does not belong to the list `A`. Thus, you replace the first `i` in the list comprehension to `i if i in A else 0`. It means that `i` is left alone if it belongs to `A`, orelse substitute `0`.